# Copiar texto a portapapeles en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, botón, edittext

En android studio como se puede copiar mediante un boton el contenido que hay en un edittext o en un textview y poder almacenarlo en portapapeles.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir alguna información que hayas encontrado? Código que tengas, etc. En google salen bastantes respuestas relacionadas, ¿has probado en buscar algo?